# How to pull an exchange rate price on Poloniex to google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet where I compute my earnings based on the exchange rate of an exchange, specifically Poloniex.com. Atm, I manually check the rates on the website and enter it manually on my sheet.

Is there a way I can pull it automatically from Poloniex so that my sheet would update itself if the rate change? They have an API but I have no idea on how to use it. If someone can point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:<from currency symbol><to currency symbol>)
```

http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/drivebunny/automatic-currency-conversion/